# undefined method `it' in RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, rspec, rspec-rails, fakeweb

I have this error when I tried to implement "Fakeweb" and I do not understand the problem.

Scenario:
"After user had filled in all the information, the system will use one of the attributes "fbid" for validation and if success then only a new company will be created, if not the process will fail."

```
Failures:
1) Companies new company create with valid information correct facebook id validates facebook id
 Failure/Error: it "should create a company" do
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `it' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_3::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x00000102fb84e0>
 # ./spec/requests/companies_spec.rb:40:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

companies_spec.rb

```
    describe "correct facebook id" do               
        #validate fbid
        it "validates facebook id" do
            FakeWeb.register_uri(:head, "http://graph.facebook.com/examplecompany", :username => 'examplecompany')
            Company.new(:url => "http://graph.facebook.com/examplecompany").fb_id_string.should eq('examplecompany')

            it "should create a company" do 
                expect { click_button submit }.to change(Company, :count).by(1)
            end
```

model/company.rb

```
def fb_id_string
    uri = URI.parse(url)
    response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) { |http| http.request_head(uri.path) }
    response["username"].to_str
end
```

end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since doing a Google search for `rspec nested it` doesn't yield anything, I thought I'd elaborate a little on @apneadiving's comment.

While rspec allows `describe` and its synonyms to be nested arbitrarily and while `it` is similar to `describe` in its structure when passed a string argument, an `it` block can only contain mocks, expectations, application code and vanilla Ruby. It cannot contain other invocations of `it` or, for that matter, `before`, `after` or `let`.  It can invoke `subject`, but doing so just invokes the block that subject was defined as; it will not redefine subject.

Conversely, mocks and expectations cannot be expressed directly within `describe`.  They must be contained within `it`.